How to tune below query
Please help suggest how to tune below postgres query.
select distinct c.aid, jsonb_array_elements (cvp.value::jsonb) as somejson
from
cont c
join compara_values cvp on c.id=cvp.cont_instance_id
join compara_temp cpt on cvp.parameter_id = cpt.parameter_id
where 
cpt."name" in ('ipay')
and cvp.value is not null
and length(cvp.value::text) > 0

explain plan shows a parallel sequential scan which is most costly on compara_values table

Maybe you'd like to actually show us the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, SETTINGS..? And maybe the tables' DDL? And maybe a fiddle? The more info you give, the more help you'll get! No need to use quoted identifiers!

Please provide information as instructed here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info
